# How to pass null value from asp.net c# to sql query?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist in which data bind dynamically. Let me explore it.
I used five dropdownlist what i have to do is have to pass null value if index 0 is selected.
 I've tried like this but returns empty string.

```
 drp_sub_stream.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select a Sub Stream", null));
 drp_sub_stream.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select a Sub Stream", DBNull.Value.ToString()));
```

Then i tried like this

```
drp_sub_stream.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select a Sub Stream", "NULL"));
```

but it returns null as a string. I've to pass this value on button click from where I'm searching the data. 
Button Click Code:

```
 public void _SearchCollege(string _CountryName,string _University, string _LevelName, string _Interest,string _Substream)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {

            con.Open();

            //string s = "select * from edu_college_desc where (country= @country and university=@university and leveln= @level and interest= @interest and substream=@substream) or (country=@country or university=@university or leveln=@level or interest=@interest or substream=@substream) ";

            string s= "select * from edu_college_desc where country = ISNULL(@country ,country) and university = ISNULL(@university ,university)   and leveln      =   ISNULL(@level ,leveln) and interest    =   ISNULL(@interest ,interest) and substream   =   ISNULL(@substream,substream)";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(s, con);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", _CountryName);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@university", _University);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level",_LevelName);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@interest", _Interest);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@substream", _Substream);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["edusearch"] = dt;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("edusearch.aspx");

            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["edusearch"] = null;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("edusearch.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

Need Solution.

Comment: What are you really tring to do? Tring to pass the null value to Sql Statement, or use in Parameter?

Comment: You can simply pass `DBNull.Value`. e.g. - `da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@substream", DBNull.Value);` where you need to pass null as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
drp_sub_stream.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select a Sub Stream", "0"));
```

or

```
drp_sub_stream.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select a Sub Stream", String.Empty));
```

Then you can use a simple if SelectedValue equals zero or string.Empty and decide if apply and filter (concatenation in sql query)

```
string s= "select * from edu_college_desc where country = ISNULL(@country ,country) and university = ISNULL(@university ,university)   and leveln      =   ISNULL(@level ,leveln) and interest    =   ISNULL(@interest ,interest)";
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_SubStream))
    s+= " and substream   =   ISNULL(@substream,substream)";
...


if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_Substream)) 
   da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@substream", _Substream);
```

In this way you can also use a required validator to check if you have selected a value (in zero case, you have to add `InitialValue="0"`)

Comment: It's correct. Then you edit your method to add `and substream   =   ISNULL(@substream,substream)` and  `da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@substream", _Substream);`
 only `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(substream))`

Comment: can you elaborate it?

Comment: I didn't understand can you please write proper snippet code.